# You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String Error

Tags: php, sql-server, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm trying to output a `Grid` from an `SQL` source by using `PHP` but it dosen't work.

Here's the error I get in the console:

```
[W] For WAI-ARIA compliance, IMG elements SHOULD have an alt attribute.
[E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\EmployeeMenu\_data\employee\Read_employee.php on line <i>14</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0019</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242280</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}( )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\EmployeeMenu\_data\employee\Read_employee.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Read_employee.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\EmployeeMenu\_data\employee\Read_employee.php on line <i>14</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0019</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242280</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}( )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\EmployeeMenu\_data\employee\Read_employee.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Read_employee.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
[{"id":null,"firstname":"Alain","lastname":"Doyon","title":"Project Manager","businessunit":"Dev","experience":"7"},{"id":null,"firstname":"Joel","lastname":"Deslauriers","title":"Integrator Senior","businessunit":"Kappa","experience":"5"}]
```

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once"..//..//_includes/headers.php";



$query = "select firstname, lastname, title, businessunit, experience from 
employee_tab order by businessunit";
logit($query);
$result = odbc_exec($connection,$query);
$cnt = 0;
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))

{ 
$cnt = $cnt + 1;
$myArray[] = array(
    'id'=>$row['id'],
    'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
    'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
    'title'=>$row['title'],
    'businessunit'=>$row['businessunit'],
    'experience'=>$row['experience'],
    );


}

if (isset($myArray))
{
    if ( sizeof($myArray) > 0 )
    {
        $output = json_encode($myArray);
        echo $output;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '(success:true,"error":0)';    
    }
}
else
    {
        echo '(success:true,"error":0)';
    }

?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there 'id' in resultset? Try without 'id'=>$row['id'].

Comment: Your PHP's output begins with a notice, which is never a valid Json. You should follow the notices and "clean" your php code.

Comment: Further, you are only echoing valid json when "echo $output", your echos in else cases do not output valid json.

Comment: Hi remove the notice and also tje rowid since a dont use an ID column for this part of my code and it work fine.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you have `display_errors` turned on, and therefore get warnings about things, corrupting your JSON.

Turn it off in your php.ini

The best error logging experience is by tailing the log in the terminal without it displaying in your screen.

Do an `isset()` check on Read_employee.php on line 14 for a start! Good luck

Comment: or disable it in the php file
`ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

The message is self explaining : `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\EmployeeMenu\_data\employee\Read_employee.php on line <i>14</i>`

Your $query request will return only "firstname, lastname, title, businessunit, experience" columns, not the "id" , but you use ['id'] in the while loop. Et paf, warning !

Comment: the real problem is he's displaying errors on screen, corrupting his output json. yes, he should fix that, but he needs to turn it off, and instead check his log!